# Single core jvm concurrency: are invisible updates possible?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, java-memory-model

If you have multiple cores and 2 threads share one non-volatile field (first only reads from it and second make some writes) there could be situation when first thread doesn't see the actual value of this field after second thread updates it, because this new value can be stored in cache of another core.

Is the same is true for single core environment? Are different caches the only cause of such inconsistency (I don't consider now race conditions ad other concurrency issues)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler may conclude that the variable cannot change within some block and optimize additional loads away, thus preventing them from being observed, even in a single-core environment.

And I wonder why you're even asking. You should program against the guarantees of the language / the java-memory-model, not some platform/implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: it's just to understand what's going on better, not for practice

Comment: @ka4eli An example of this good answer is this. Imagine a simple: `while(!stop) { ... }` in the reader thread where `stop` is the shared variable. The compiler is allowed to rewrite it as `boolean temp = stop; while (!temp) {...}` (it's called variable hoisting). If that happens your reader thread will, obviously, never see the updated value because it won't even try to read it... If `stop` is volatile the optimisation is not allowed.